# What Exception is thrown when an implementation breaks its interface's contract?

Tags: java, interface, exception

Through a good amount of debugging (I do not wish to repeat) I've found a circumstance that can only be arrived at if one of my objects was given a comparator that breaks its interface's contract (namely a Comparator for which `compare(a, a)` returns a non-zero value).

What kind of exception should I throw?

I thought I could take inspiration from TreeMap, which takes a comparator, but it simply acts bizarrely (not throwing an exception) if you give it a nonsense comparator.

Comment: an interface can not determine what the method should return, only the type. is there an exception foreseen in the interface?

Comment: Aren't you getting: *Java Comparison method violates its general contract* ?

Comment: All comparison operations will throw `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` with the message **Comparison method violates its general contract!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way is to use the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`:

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("One of the objects given breaks the comparators interface contract ");
```

You can take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to trigger it, as I tried some examples myself, but `Arrays.sort` can

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException(
            "Comparison method violates its general contract!");
```

Found in the code for [TimSort](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/TimSort.java#747). I have seen this message before.

Comment: A typical way I've seen is to implement your comparator like `return (a >= b) ? 1 : -1;`, i.e. ignoring the possibility of equality.

Comment: @AndyTurner I tried `ints.sort((a, b) -> 1)` and similar.

Comment: @PeterLawrey This generally works - not sure what the requirements are though... http://ideone.com/asOlrx